# Table of Contents Style

Tags: table-of-contents, xetex, fontspec, titletoc

I really enjoy the table of contents formatting (all sections of a chapter in a single paragraph), of the [Motion Mountain's physics books](http://www.motionmountain.net/index.html). Does anyone know how to reproduce that kind of style? Is there a LaTeX package for managing TOC styles?

BTW, I need to use XeLaTeX, and it seems to exist an incompatibility between 'fontspec' and 'titletoc'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [tocloft](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) and [titletoc](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titletoc) packages let you customize the table of contents. In your case, the second package could be a better choice: the starred version of `\titlecontents` groups the entries in a single paragraph.

Here's a little example (of course, feel free to adapt it according to your needs):

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\titlecontents{chapter}[0pt\addvspace{15pt}]
{\llap{\makebox[3em]{\oldstylenums{\thecontentspage\hfill\thecontentslabel}}\hskip1em}
  \small\scshape\vskip-\baselineskip}{}{}{}
\titlecontents*{section}[20pt]
{\upshape}{}{}
{, \oldstylenums{\thecontentspage}}[][\ \textbullet\ ][]

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{Test chapter one}
\section{Test section one one}
\section{Test section one two}
\section{Test section one three}
\section{Test section one four}
\section{Test section one five}
\chapter{Test chapter two}
\section{Test section two one}
\section{Test section two two}
\section{Test section two three}

\end{document}
```

The resulting ToC:

[image]

EDIT: as Alan Munn noticed in a comment, the above example fails to compile with `fontspec` and `xelatex`, due to the `\addvspace{15pt}` command in the first optional argument of `\titlecontents{chapter}`; a possible workaround would be to introduce the vertical skip in the second mandatory argument of `\titlecontents`:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{fontspec,xltxtra}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\titlecontents{chapter}[0pt]
{\vskip15pt\llap{\makebox[3em]{\oldstylenums{\thecontentspage\hfill\thecontentslabel}}\hskip1em}
  \small\scshape\vskip-\baselineskip}{}{}{}
\titlecontents*{section}[20pt]
{\upshape}{}{}
{, \oldstylenums{\thecontentspage}}[][\ \textbullet\ ][]

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{Test chapter one}
\section{Test section one one}
\section{Test section one two}
\section{Test section one three}
\section{Test section one four}
\section{Test section one five}

\chapter{Test chapter two}
\section{Test section two one}
\section{Test section two two}
\section{Test section two three}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice... But it seems to be incompatible with `fontspec` and xelatex? For example, by adding: \usepackage{fontspec,xltxtra}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Hoefler Text}

Comment: Damn: http://www.macfreek.nl/mindmaster/LaTeX_package_conflicts#XeTeX_and_titletoc

Comment: @Hugo S Ferreira: indeed, there seems to be an incompatibility and I don't know a workaround. I'll try to think of something. Perhaps you should add the information to your question (about you using `XeLaTeX` and `fontspec`).

Comment: @Hugo Interestingly, it doesn't work even if I remove the titletoc stuff. Without a bug report (please, do) it's difficult to say where the problem is. As to the link, note it says `\vspace{3px}` and the error is what you could expect, since px is not a unit in TeX or XeTeX.

Comment: The error is caused by the `\addvspace{15pt}` command in the `\titlecontents{chapter}` command.  That's the minimal document that fails.

Comment: @Hugo S Ferreira: I've updated my answer (see Alan's comment).

Comment: Thank you! I've awarded the bounty, although I think Alan should have had a share of it :-)

Comment: @Gonzalo Do you have any idea *why* it fails inside the optional argument? The `titletoc` code is quite complicated and I couldn't figure out a reason. (@Hugo: Thanks for the kind words. I'm just happy to have helped.)

Comment: @Alan: no idea. The error message produced by the original code comes from the `calc` package. From the documentation I got "After a value has been read, `\calc@post@scan` is called, and expects a binary operator, a sequence of right parentheses, a `!` character, or `\relax`." Obviously, `\addvspace` is not one of the expected tokens and this triggers the error message, but then I wonder why it works OK without `fontspec`. We'll have to ask Javier.